# Filter/ Compare 2 hashMaps in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, filter, hashmap, compare

I need some help figuring this out!

So i take userInput in forms of names: String and age: Int. These are added in an hashMap called allMenInfo. I have already added some values and keys to have something to compare with. I want to filter/ compare **only** the Values(Int) in allMenInfo with allWomenInfo. How whould I go about in doing so ?

```
fun main() {
   val allMen = AllMenInfo2()
   allMen.takeUserName()

}

open class AllMenInfo2 {

   val allMenInfo = hashMapOf(Pair("Bob", 18), Pair("Ken", 21), Pair("Jerry", 25), Pair("Smith", 26))
   val allWomenInfo = hashMapOf(Pair("Alice", 19), Pair("Rebeca", 20), Pair("Olivia", 21), Pair("Clara", 22), Pair("Julia", 23))

   open fun takeUserName() {
       println("Enter your name!")
       val userName = readLine()?:""
       val names = userName
       println(allMenInfo)

       try {
           println("Please enter your age!")
           val ageOfUsers = readLine()?:""
           val ages = ageOfUsers.toInt()
           allMenInfo.put(names, ages)


       } catch (E: Exception) {
           println("Invalid number/name, please try again!")
       }

       println(allMenInfo)
       println(allWomenInfo)

   }

}
```

Comment: Compare them how? Filtering you can just do ``allMenInfo.filter { (name, age) -> age == 20 }`` or whatever. When you iterate over a `Map` you get `Entry`s which are basically a key/value pair, that's what's getting passed into that filter predicate there - you can compare whatever you like using that

Comment: Also just as a tip - instead of ``Pair("Bob", 18)`` you can write ``"Bob" to 18``. It's how you usually write map entries, but it works anytime you need a ``Pair``, it's a nice shorthand

Comment: The sentence: _I want to filter/ compare only the Values(Int) in allMenInfo with allWomenInfo._ is not clearly stating what you are trying to do.

Comment: @cactustictacs. Thanks for the answer. Thats a very good advice as well using Pair, will remember it! :D As for the question, what I like to achieve is: 1. I want to be able to input a name and an age for which will be stored in the hashMap (allMenInfo) together with the other Pairs. 2. I want to take the entire collection of hashMap (allMenInfo) and match it vs allWomenInfo. 3. It should now only by age I entered, filter out everyone besides the one with the same age as me in the allWomenInfo hashmap.

Comment: Hope this made it more clear!

Comment: Not really tbh! What do you mean when you say you want to take the entire collection of `allMenInfo`, and "match it" vs `allWomenInfo`? Groups of people who all have the same age? `allMenInfo.plus(allWomenInfo).entries.groupBy { (_, age) -> age}`. Just women of a certain age? Same as the filter one I posted, but run on ``allWomenInfo`` instead. It might help to post an example of what you want to happen, because there's lots of ways you can interpret this

Comment: yeah, I want to match  just with women who has the same age. Something like this; Lets say I enter name "Smith" and **age = 20**. This will be added to the hashMap of allMenInfo. I want the program then to compare the ages (allMenInfo) with allWomenInfo and only filter out the women with name and **age(20)** to match my input(the age I put in). Something like this: If(myInputInAge == values(Int) in allWomenInfo) "then match all women with the same age as me/that I input"

Comment: I went through the code a few more times. I re-made and re-posted the code to make my scope more clear. Hopefully it should be easier to solve the problem now!